# Is Defi-al.com a scam?

Tags: scam

Good morning,

I would like to check the authenticity of the following company in Defi Wallet, which name is Defi-al.com.

I have been using this for a week or so, and I think I have fallen into a scam.

One day I opened the app and I got a notification saying the following:

“ETH Airdrop Event Rewards

Mining Pool Event Bonus ERC-20 Smart Pledge Contract, participate now and get 35 ETH Event Bonus”

But in order to receive the bonus I had to  pay an amount of USDT.

After I reached the required amount the money never arrived because the customer support informed me that anti money laundry system detected a possible fraud.

Also they told me that in Oder to “unblock” my account I need to pay 50% of the total amount of money which I invested so far and I have only 10 days to do so.

Does anyone know this website in defi wallet?
Is this a common procedure or a scam?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Customer Seevice wrote this: “Dear user, the system has detected that the member ID://// has completed the activity of depositing funds in multiple wallets, and the system has triggered the anti-money laundering regulations. For the security of your funds, the system has frozen your ID: ////. You need to unfreeze your account and restore your account status before you can withdraw money normally. Dear customer, Recovery account is provided with the usual trading wallet address. Upon approval, 50% of the deposit needs to be transferred to activate the locked account. thank you.
“

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It looks very much like a typical scam site.

The domain registration is quite recent from October 2023.

The site doesn't show up until you connect with a wallet.